# Remove double blank pages after chapters

Tags: blank-page

Sometimes, but not systematically, when my chapters end on an odd page, a blank page is inserted afterwards.

Sometimes, but not systematically, when my chapters end on an even page *two* blank pages are inserted.

These pages are numbered. I would like to remove all of these blank pages.
So far, I've tried:

- `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage` at the end of the chapters
- The `openany` option in the document class
- The `oneside` option in the document class

None of these have succeeded in removing the blank pages.

This wasn't happening at first, and it suddenly started happening after I moved some figures around. In fact, this issue doesn't appear in the chapters before the figures I moved around (which are all in the same chapter).

My document class is an `scrbook`, and it compiles with 0 warnings and 0 errors.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

EDIT:
Here's a little more precision: Chapters 1, 2, and 3 work fine (No blank pages inserted). Chapter 4 has the aforementioned figures that seem to have started this whole thing, ends on an even page, and is followed by two blank pages. Chapter 5 ends on an even page and is followed by two blank pages. Chapter 6 ends on an odd page and is followed by one blank page.

I've fiddled around and as it turns out, commenting out chapter 4 fixes the problem for chapters 5 and 6, and commenting out any other chapter changes nothing. Commenting out chapter 4 does not change the evenness of the pages for chapters 5 and 6.

Comment: Two blank pages shouldn't happen, ever.  This indicates that something invisible wound up on the last (odd) page.  Without a minimal example which demonstrates the problem, there is no way to know that that invisible thing is.

Comment: a blank page after an odd page is the default behaviour, the `openany` option will prevent that. two blank pages would be a bug or more likely user error, typical cause would include having `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph for example.

Comment: @JohnKormylo But the single blank pages shouldn't be happening either with the `openany` option, nor should it be inconsistent.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That wouldn't explain the fact that chapter 4 has an effect on chapters 5 and 6.

Comment: You will need to post an example impossible to guess otherwise, it does not need to be big, just find the smallest subset of the document with the problem, then you can replace (say) every paragrah by `a\\a\\a\\a\\a` with the right number of lines and every image by `\rule{3cm}{4cm}` or whatever size is needed, so you get an example that shows the problem. latex never acts inconsistently, it just follows the instructions in the document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm trying to do that right now, I just thought it would be best to post first in case someone knew what direction to steer me in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out (at least in my document), `\topskip0pt` (which I added whilst fiddling with the figures) causes all of the subsequent chapters to exhibit the behaviour I describe in my question. Changing it to `\topskip1pt` fixed the problem without significantly changing the layout.

Comment: You could probably change it to `\topskip 1sp` to make the change *completely* insignificant (1/65536 pt)